# Not able to get correct output using below code looping array of object inside for loop its only taking last condition

Tags: javascript

Find below code for more details

```js
var A1  = ["1","2","5","6"];

var A2 = [
    {label:"one", value:"1"},
    {label:"two", value:"2"},
    {label:"three", value:"3"},
    {label:"four", value:"4"},
    {label:"five", value:"5"},
    {label:"six", value:"6"},
];
for(var i=0; i<A2.length; i++){
    for(var j=0; j<A1.length; j++ ){
        if(A1[i] == A2[j].value){
            A2[ i ].disabled == true;
        }
        else{
            A2[ i ].disabled == false;
        }
    }
}         
console.log( JSON.stringify( A2 ) );
```

I want the following output:

```
[{"label":"one","value":"1","disabled":true}, 
{"label":"two","value":"2","disabled":true}, 
{"label":"three","value":"3","disabled":false}, 
{"label":"four","value":"4","disabled":false}, 
{"label":"five","value":"5","disabled":true}, 
{"label":"six","value":"6","disabled":true}]
```

Comment: What is the output you are expecting?

Comment: @Mamun [
    {label:"one", value:"1", disabled:true},
    {label:"two", value:"2", disabled:true},
    {label:"three", value:"3", disabled:false},
    {label:"four", value:"4", disabled:false},
    {label:"five", value:"5", disabled:true},
    {label:"six", value:"6", disabled:true}
]

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Answer (score 1):

You need a single loop and check if the value is in `a2`. then set `disabled` to this boolean value.

In the question, you mixed up `i` and `j` and you set a value for any values of `a1`. The result is more or less random.

BTW, i changed all variables to starting with lower case, because in Javascript usually variables with starting upper case are reserved for instanciable functions or classes.

```js
var a1 = ["1", "2", "5", "6"],
    a2 = [{ label: "one", value: "1" }, { label: "two", value: "2" }, { label: "three", value: "3" }, { label: "four", value: "4" }, { label: "five", value: "5" }, { label: "six", value: "6" }],
    i;

for (i = 0; i < a2.length; i++) {
    a2[i].disabled = a1.includes(a2[i].value);
}
console.log(a2);
```

Your code with comments.

```js
var A1 = ["1", "2", "5", "6"];

var A2 = [
    { label: "one", value: "1" },
    { label: "two", value: "2" },
    { label: "three", value: "3" },
    { label: "four", value: "4" },
    { label: "five", value: "5" },
    { label: "six", value: "6" },
];
for (var i = 0; i < A2.length; i++) {
    A2[i].disabled = false;               // do not use a comparison, take an assignment
                                          // set to false as default value
    for (var j = 0; j < A1.length; j++) {
        if (A1[j] == A2[i].value) {       // i and j switched
            A2[i].disabled = true;        // same here with comparison where you need
                                          // an assignment
        }
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(A2));
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think you are omitting the number "3" in the array i.e**

```
var A1 = ["1","2","5","6"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Is scoping that's causing that result...

```
var A1 = ["1", "2", "5", "6"];
var A2 = [{
  label: "one",
  value: "1"
}, {
  label: "two",
  value: "2"
}, {
  label: "three",
  value: "3"
}, {
  label: "four",
  value: "4"
}, {
  label: "five",
  value: "5"
}, {
  label: "six",
  value: "6"
} ];

for (var i = 0; i < A2.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < A1.length; j++) {
    if (A1[i] == A2[j].value) {
      A2[i].disabled = true;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(A2[i]))
    } else {
      A2[i].disabled = false;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(A2[i]))
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

[Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

> The `includes()` method determines whether an array includes a certain element, returning true or false as appropriate.

It seem's pretty straight with `map()` and `includes()`:

```js
var A1 = ["1","2","5","6"]; 
var A2 = [ {label:"one", value:"1"}, {label:"two", value:"2"}, {label:"three", value:"3"}, {label:"four", value:"4"}, {label:"five", value:"5"}, {label:"six", value:"6"}]; 

A2 = A2.map(i => {
  if(A1.includes(i.value))
    i.disabled = true;
  else
    i.disabled = false;
  return i;
});

console.log( JSON.stringify(A2) );
```

Answer (score 0):

It is taking last condition because it is a nested loop

```
for(var i=0; i<A2.length; i++){
    for(var j=0; j<A1.length; j++ ){
        if(A1[i] == A2[j].value){
            A2[ i ].disabled == true;
        }
        else{
            A2[ i ].disabled == false;
        }
    }
}
```

A2[ i ] is getting overwritten on each loop iteration because the loop above it is incrementing j not i, so at the end you will see only the effect of last value of j

2nd thing which is already being pointed out is you have to assign

```
A2[ i ].disabled == true;
```

using single = sign